# How to assign a value to a a JS variable in a web site depending if it's running locally or in production?

Tags: javascript, variables, production-environment

I work on web project on my laptop. When I'm done I upload my files to production. Every time I upload to production, I've to make sure I change various URLs in my javascript code to production URLs. For example:

```
var ping_url = 'http://10.10.128.233'      // locally
//var ping_url = 'http://ping.service.com' // in production
```

I've 3 urls like this in different parts of code. I often forget to change them before uploading to production, and as a result I break production website.

Is there a way to check if I'm running the website in laptop or in production?

I'd like to write:

```
if (local) {
  var ping_url = 'http://10.10.128.233'      // locally
}
else {
  var ping_url = 'http://ping.service.com' // in production
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always inspect [`location.hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.hostname) and compare it to `'localhost'` or whatever hostname you use on your laptop. For example

```
var ping_url = ~location.hostname.indexOf('localhost')
    ? 'http://10.10.128.233' : 'http://ping.service.com'
```

Comment: @W.D.: that will make no difference if the OP has done `var location = {}` in the global scope.

Comment: Also, this might not work if you use `::1` or `127.0.0.1` to connect to your local dev server.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you have a *deployment system* which prepares and deploys your app and in the process takes care of environmental differences. For example, I'm partial to [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com). To deploy my projects, I type `cap deploy` on the command line, which runs build/packaging/configuration scripts, uploads the site to the server and then runs post-migration scripts there. You can deploy different config files in this process, or post-process your Javascript files in the process. There are a lot of different ways to make this change stick, all suited for different purposes.

If you have any sort of server-side language, you may want to use any of the below:

```
<?php if (...) : ?>
    var ping_url = '...';
<? else : ?>
    var ping_url = '...';
<?php endif; ?>
```

or

```
var ping_url = <?php echo json_encode($config['pingUrl']); ?>;
```

Environment variables can be very useful here; i.e. in your Apache configuration or .htaccess file somewhere you have something like:

```
SetEnv MYAPP_ENVIRONMENT production
```

In your app you do something along these lines:

```
$environment = getenv('MYAPP_ENVIRONMENT') ?: 'development';
```

And then you decide further what your environment is.

You have to figure out which combination of server-side processing, environment variables and deploy-time processing suits you best.

Comment: Thanks so much for your insigtful answer. I will need to learn capistrano to do this. For now I went with the other solution of just checking URl in JS and seeing if it is my laptop IP.